# echo htmlentities($var) doesn't work

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I get a string from the database, and i want to output that string with the function `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`.

The problem is that when I `echo` the variable without `htmlentities`, it outputs the string just like it should, but when I `echo` the variable WITH `htmlentities`, it outputs nothing.

Code:

This works:

```
<h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<h2><?php echo htmlentities($row['title']); ?></h2>
<p><?php echo htmlentities($row['description'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); ?></p>
```

Comment: Have you seen this: "If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set." [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Also take note that the default encoding changed with PHP 5.4.0

Comment: Well, the string that has to be returned is "ford focus coupé"
I don't know what's invalid about that ...

Comment: The expected encoding is invalid. `htmlentities` expects it to be in some default encoding, but it's actually in some other encoding. You need to tell it what encoding it's in.

Comment: I editted the code :) and this still doesn't work

Comment: "ford focus coupé" has french accent characters.  Try setting the encoding flag to utf-8.

Comment: I suggest creating a wrapper function that you call, which is simply   function qHTML($string) { return htmlentities($string); } so that you can add more to it, or tweak it.  That way you can change how your entire app outputs things to the browser by making only 1 change, instead of the same change in a thousand places.  Then you just say  <h1><?php echo qHTML($row['title']); ?></h1>

Comment: What encoding is the string in then? Where does it come from?